# Finding the Chern character of a curve on the quintic threefold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, characteristic-classes

Let $X$ be the quintic threefold in $\mathbb{CP}^{4}$ defined by the vanishing of the Fermat polynomial
$$
x_{1}^{5}+x_{2}^{5}+x_{3}^{5}+x_{4}^{5}+x_{5}^{5}
$$
and consider a rational curve $D$ on $X$. I would like to compute the Chern character $ch(\mathcal{O}_{D})$ of the structure sheaf of $D$. I believe that the answer should be
$$
ch(\mathcal{O}_{D})
=
-\frac{1}{5}[H]^{2}
-
\frac{1}{5}[H]^{3}
$$
where $[H]$ is the (restriction of), the hyperplane class.

My first idea was to consider the short exact sequence
$$
0
\to\mathcal{I}_{D}
\to
\mathcal{O}_{X}
\to
\mathcal{O}_{D}
\to
0
$$
where $\mathcal{I_{D}}$ is the ideal sheaf of $D$. Then by the additivity of the Chern character, we should have
$$
ch(\mathcal{O}_{D})
=
ch(\mathcal{O}_{X})
-
ch(\mathcal{I}_{D})
$$
However, I have no idea how to identify the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_{D}$. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Certainly this should depend on the degree of the rational curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $C$ is a curve of genus $g$ then
$$
ch(\mathcal{O}_C) = 
[C] + (1 - g)[P] = 
\frac{d}5[H]^2 + \frac{1 - g}5[H]^3,
$$
where $[P]$ is the class of a point. Indeed, the top term is $[C]$ by Grothendieck--Riemann--Roch, and the bottom term is determined by Hirzebruch--Riemann--Roch (note that the canonical class of $X$ is zero).

Comment: Thanks heaps for your answer. I'm still really new to this area and was wondering if you could provide a little more detail or some references to help me understand where exactly this comes from.

Comment: Just look for GRR and HRR; both can be found in Hartshorne, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Will do. Just to make sure I understand correctly, you have identifed $[C]$ and $[P]$ with their Poincare duals in the above, right?

Comment: For me $[C]$ is the class of $C$ in $H^4(X,\mathbb{Z})$ (which corresponds under the natural isomorphism to the class of $C$ in $H_2(X, \mathbb{Z})$. Similarly for $[P]$.